# Meteor app , If we add a new cordova plugin , do we have to resubmit the app or will meter hotcode push take care of it?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, meteor, phonegap

So our app is already submitted and approved in apple and google play stores , I have a need to launch app from a link and thinking of using url scheme cordova plugin to launch the app from a link ,question is if I add this cordova plugin and build the app , do i need to resubmit the app to the stores or will the hot code push take care of this ?From my understanding , any new cordova plugin requires a new app build and submission to the app stores . If this is the case , then users will have to upgrade the app in their devices which i want to avoid at the present stage.

Appreciate all your answers.
Thanks

Comment: At the very least you will need a new app store release on iOS as the supported URL schemes are contained in the info.plist file which is part of the signed bundle and cannot be updated without a new release.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, any change in Cordova plugins (actually anything that is not simply loaded like a web page) will require an update in the app and play store.

Hot Code Push can only handle JS, HTML, CSS and assets in the `public` folder. This is also a constraint from the App Store policy, which allows bypassing a new approval only for what is processed by JavaScript Core.